# I know the output of the following code will be 1000 4 but why 1000 4 not 4 1000?

Tags: c

I know the output of the following code will be 1000 4 but why 1000 4 not 4 1000 ?

```
int a=1000;

printf("%d",printf("%d",a));
```

Comment: Why would it be  `4 1000`?

Comment: How it's actually printing ..as it's left to right associative so first it should print  4 then 1000 .. :(

Comment: actually, I would expect `10004` (no space)

Comment: @WhozCraig good one :)

Comment: Before calling `printf` (the inner one), how would it know what it returned?

Comment: the embedded printf() will be executed first by printing 1000, THEN its returned value '4' which will be printed by the outer printf().

Answer (score 6):

I think you forget, that the printf as argument get's first printed and then the return value gets used as parameter for the outer printf statement! That's why you get:

```
10004
```

```
printf("%d", printf("%d",a));
//^^^^     //^^^^^^ 1. prints 1000 
//|        //| 2. return value get's used for the outer printf statement
//| 3. prints the return value of the inner printf statement 4
```

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` function writes a formatted string to the `stdout`, and returns the number of characters written. In the beginning it writes the value of `a` which is 1000; after that `4` is returned, and passed to the outer `printf` invocation that prints `4`, thus the output `10004`.

In other words, the arguments must be evaluated before the function call is made; the result of `printf("%s", a)` is given as an argument to the other `printf`, thus its value must be evaluated *before* the outer `printf` can be called.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to a function are evaluated before a function is called.

`printf("%d",a)` is executed first, outputting `1000` then `printf("%d",4)` is called, outputing `4`

Answer (score 0):

`printf`, on success, returns an `int` equal to the number of characters written. The internal `printf` gets called first, printing 1000, and then the return of `printf` (i.e. 4) gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at those 'printfs' as they're laid out in the code.
But when actually printing to the console, what matters is order of execution.

And the order is:

- first print 1000,
- then print value returned from first call to printf.

  Hence `10004`.

If you wanted to see `41000` as a result you'd have to know value returned from printf **before** it was called, and that's just, well...